# Spring receive data from the client

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Good evening!

```
 public class Order  {
   private int idOrder;
   private Basket basket;
// getter and setter
 }

public class AnonymousOrder  {
  private String name;
  private String telephone;
// getter and setter
}

public class UserOrder  {
  private User user;
// getter and setter
}


public class OrdersForm {
  private List< ? extends  Order> orders;    
 // getter and setter  
}

@RequestMapping(value="/showOrders")
 public String showOrders(Model model){
    List<? extends Order> orders= adminManager.searchAllOrders();
    OrdersShowForm ordersForm = new OrdersShowForm();
    ordersForm.setOrders(orders);
    model.addAttribute("ordersForm", ordersForm);
    return "showOrders";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/showOrders", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showOrdersPOST(@ModelAttribute("ordersForm") OrdersShowForm ordersForm){

    System.out.print(ordersForm);
    return "showOrders";
```

}

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="ordersForm">   
    <table class="features-table" border="1">
              <c:forEach items="${ordersForm.orders}" var="order" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <c:if test="${order['class'].simpleName != 'UserOrder'}">
                    <td>
                        <input name="orders[${status.index}].name" value="${order.name}"/>

                    </td>
                </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
   </table>
```

Problem: I am passing on page two types of data: UserOrder and AnonymousOrder, but when I try to get them on the server then come data type Order.
Question: How to transfer data to the server without changing their actual type?

P.S. sorry for my English)

Comment: I suspect that the actual type is not changed. You can iterate over the collection that comes to the server an check every Order with 'instanceof' operator.

Comment: @Evgeny in debugger shows that all the elements are of the type Order